# Selenium Handle conditional assert

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I am doing a UI action and there are 2 possibilities;

```
1. I get an info message OR
2. I get a success message
```

Now I need to assert the same in Selenium.

Again there is only one outcome possible on the UI...either I get an info message OR i get a success message..

So basically I need to assert on either of the following;

```
assertThat(getAlertMessage("info", "cancel info message").getText(), equalTo("cancel info message"));

assertThat(getAlertMessage("success", "cancel success message").getText(), equalTo("cancel success message"));
```

Should I do a try catch OR use if...else ?

Comment: Which tool are you using to do the asserts? Junit, TestNG or some other tool?

Comment: Are you looking to using hamcrest matchers in your assert?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the assertion methods that take booleans as parameters and just do a conditional OR check:

For TestNG:

```
String alertMessage = getAlertMessage("info", "cancel info message").getText();
String infoMessage = "cancel info message";
String successMessage = "cancel success message";

assertTrue(alertMessage.equals(infoMessage) || alertMessage.equals(successMessage), "Alert message does not equal either info or success message");
```

For JUnit:

```
String alertMessage = getAlertMessage("info", "cancel info message").getText();
String infoMessage = "cancel info message";
String successMessage = "cancel success message";

assertTrue("Alert message does not equal either info or success message", alertMessage.equals(infoMessage) || alertMessage.equals(successMessage));
```

If you are using Hamcrest matchers, you can do this:

```
assertThat(alertMessage, anyOf(equalTo(infoMessage), equalTo(successMessage)));
```